# jupyterlab terminal broken: how to diagnose?

Tags: shell, jupyter-lab

I am launching a pre-cooked AWS container (which has many good stuff that I don't want to build from scratch) but has a broken Jupyterlab terminal (screen shot below):

- tab completion does not work
- when I source `~./bashrc`, the `PS1` is taken verbatim

[image]

Any ideas how to diagnose what got messed up?

Answer (score 0):

From the `shopt not found` error, I got a clue I may not be in BASH.

First, I checked which shell I was using

`echo "$SHELL"`

and it was empty.

I launched BASH: `bash` and everything works as it should now